# password_verify - password hashing

Tags: php, passwords

I am testing different ways to encrypt passwords and I have used the majority of ways except I am confused on the password_verify function for the script I am using and how I could implement it within a script(Look below). This script involves signing up and logging in etc. The script successfully hashes the password with this line of code below.

```
$passwordhash = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

(from signup)

but when I try to use password verify in my login script it does not work. So my question is how can i use the password_verify function in the code below.

```
<?php
//this is executed on another page
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    // Connect to db
    include_once("databaseconnection.php");
    //gather posted and sanitize
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = ($_POST['p']);
    //user ip
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
    //data error handling end
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        } else {
            //create session cookies
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
            //update certain fields ip, last login time
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

(I tried, and failed, with this code using the password_verify funcion)

```
$p = password_verify( $_POST['p'], $passwordhash );
```

Sorry if this is hard to understand but it will be very much appreciated if I someone could help :-)

Comment: password_verify function will return a boolean. You need to use if condition to check the statement is true

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [Second Order SQLi](https://haiderm.com/second-order-sql-injection-explained-example/). Always use parameters rather than `mysqli_real_escape_string` as you will find it much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the password you are storing in the DB is already hashed the problem your having is that you just can't verify the password since you are comparing a plain text password against a hashed code.

I believe changing

```
if($p != $db_pass_str){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    }
```

to

```
if(!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)) {
       echo "login_failed";
        exit();
}
```

Should fix your problem, have a look at the [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: The password in my db is already hashed successfully. With the code above should I change the line    $p = ($_POST['p']);  or should I just leave it the same? Thanks for your help.

Comment: keep it the same, the $p = $_POST['p'] just assigns the password which is sent via the browser to a variable. So you want it the same then use password verify which internally checks to see if the hash of the plain text password matches the hash provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

> $p = ($_POST['p']);

but then nothing is done to change $p before this:

> if($p != $db_pass_str){

Thinking of what is typical, it's atypical for the hashing to be done client side and atypical for the database to store the password in plain text, so my best guess is that the form is passing an unhashed password and the database is storing a hashed password. Leading to the second quoted line failing unless you were to enter the password hash in the login form.

If that is not the problem, then perhaps post some additional context.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is slightly easier(but less secure) using md5 and sha1. I would usually just add md5 to it like so $p = md5($_POST['p']); but using password_verify it is hard to translate it in such a way because I can't just put password_verify infront of it like md5.   $p = password_verify($_POST['p']); would not work.